# ArangoDB IS_DATE AQL Function

Tags: validation, date, arangodb

I have a number of items in a collection that have a dateDue field on them. Some have this dateDue field set to an ISO8601 date, and others have null, and some others have a blank string. I want to do the following:

```
filter DATE_COMPARE(DATE_NOW(), dateDue, "years", "days")
```

However, if dateDue is null or a blank string this throws an error. I can add this to solve it:

```
filter w.dateDue != null and w.dateDue != ""
filter DATE_COMPARE(DATE_NOW(), dateDue, "years", "days")
```

But that only covers null values and blank strings. Sure this may be enough, but I would like to ensure that any record that does not have a valid date for the dateDue field is excluded. I was expecting to see an IS_DATE function for Arango, but I couldn't find one in the manual anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: `DATE_TIMESTAMP` does not throw for invalid iso8601 dates but returns null and give warnings:
`return DATE_TIMESTAMP("2015-50-04T04:44:42.505Z") != null`
another way maybe is to write custom aql function
`isNaN(new Date("2015-50-04T04:44:42.505Z"))`
and i'm not sure a better way exists

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no `IS_DATE` function or something similar in AQL, so using filters as above is definitely one way to do it.

To make it a bit easier in the future, an `IS_DATESTRING` AQL function has been added in the 2.8 branch today. This will allow writing the filter as follows:

```
FILTER IS_DATESTRING(w.dateDue)
FILTER DATE_COMPARE(DATE_NOW(), w.dateDue, "years", "days")
```

Comment: Great I look forward to the IS_DATESTRING feature!

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the standard ISO8601 format of momentjs, a very popular javascript date library, doesn't seem to mix well with the ISO8601 format in Arango. For example:

Comment: DATE_FORMAT("2015-12-18T18:40:48-06:00", "%yyyy-%mm-%dd") == "2015-12-19"

Comment: Not sure what you mean and where the mismatch is: `DATE_FORMAT("2015-12-18T18:40:48-06:00", "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")` returns indeed the string `2015-12-19`, which is expected. The result also seems correct as `new Date("2015-12-18T18:40:48-06:00").toISOString()` is equal to UTC `2015-12-19T00:40:48.000Z`, and all date values in ArangoDB work on UTC.

Comment: Hmmm... I must not understand the date value exactly. Why is 2015-12-19 the expected value of DATE_FORMAT("2015-12-18T18:40:48-06:00", "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")? The date portion of the string is "2015-12-18..."

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` would be a pretty dumb function if it only took a substring of the input. Instead, it actually parses the input date to a date object at UTC time. Your input is UTC-6 and 18:40:48 + 6 hours for Zulu time (UTC+0) is 00:40:48 the next day. The day after the 18th of December is the 19th. ArangoDB uses Zulu time only, there is currently no way to retain the input timezone for the calculations or formatting.

Comment: Regarding `IS_DATESTRING()`: The current implementation only checks if the input string is **like** a date string, it does not check if it's a valid date(string). Thus, I expect certain queries to still fail, e.g. for "2015-02-29" (not a leap year, thus no 29th February). Such a date can't be produced by any of the DATE functions however, it can only occur if you blindly inserted user entered dates into your database.

Comment: I understand the current behavior that always uses the UTC value of the date may be counter-intuitive. I have therefore filed an issue here with request for comments: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1630